# Does rollback affect transient fields?

Tags: jpa, java-ee-6

It is strange, but I have nowhere found, how does the rollback affect transient (non persisted) field. I've found only bug report [Rollbacks affect transient fields](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PCACHE-77). But it sounds strange. If the field has been changed, the value should be revert, when transaction is rolling back. Otherwise the atomicity of transaction gets broken up, doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, transient fields can't be rolled back, because they're transient. The database is what does the rollback, and the database doesn't know about your transient fields, by definition. Even the persistent fields are not rolled back, because the persistent fields are just a snapshot of what the database contains at a given time. Once a rollback has happened, the entity should be thrown away and forgotten, because it contains invalid state.